# Knockout Live Search

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I'm currently learning knockout and are currently experimenting with the various things that can be achieved with the library. One thing I'm trying to do right is to create a 'live search'. (codepen below)

The error i'm getting is cannot read propery 'toLowerCase' of undefined. To me, my code looks right and I'm guessing there's a rookie error somewhere.

The data in self.tracks() is fetched from soundcloud and pushed into an observableArray. My HTML template renders these tracks perfectly fine if I remove all instances of 'computedTracks' - it's looking like the function can't read self.tracks()?

HTML:

```
<input placeholder="Search..." type="search" data-bind="value: searchQuery">

<div class="view-tracks">
    <ul data-bind="foreach: computedTracks">
        <li data-bind="click: $root.goToTrack">
            <span data-bind="text: track"></span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

KO:

```
self.computedTracks = ko.computed(function() {
                return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.tracks(), function(item) {
                    return item.track.toLowerCase().indexOf(self.searchQuery().toLowerCase()) >= 0;
                });
            });
```

If anybody could highlight my error in this it would be much appreciated.

Complete demo:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EHgdx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**CodeOpen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BDdHm)

The problem is that your initial value for the searchQuery observable is set to undefined. You either have to check if it is defined and then call toLowerCase() or set a default value of '' for it. Just like I did in the codeopen demo.

```
self.searchQuery = ko.observable('');
```